# Template parameter of an object validation

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to validate in this function, if the parameter `T` is of type `char*` also, how can I achieve that because in this implementation it will return false and getValue returns object of type `T`

```
template<class T>
bool Pair<T>::operator==(const Pair<T> &pair)
{
  if(strcmp(getKey(),pair.getKey())==0 && pair.getValue()==pair.getValue())
  {
      return true;
  }
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)?

Comment: So `Pair` can be used with a number of different `T`s where `char*` is one of them? Are you looking to make the `operator==` specialized for the case then `T` is `char*`?

Comment: yes that is what I look to do @super

Comment: @Karmen That is easily done, but it requires you to specialize the whole `Pair` class, you can't specialize a member function without specializing the whole class.

Comment: I cannot specialize it because the user chooses T

Comment: That's exactly what a template specialization is for. You define the template in one way, and for a certain instantiation you can give it an alternative behavior (in this case when the user chooses `char*`).

Comment: yes ,but the == operator must work one way when T=char* ,in the == operator it must to strcmp(x,y) and if T=int then do x==y I wanna divide these cases in my == operator I have shown

Comment: As I said, in order to do that you need to specialize the entire class. I will post an answer to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specialize a member function for a template class, you need to specialize the entire class. Here is a bare minimum example to give you an idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template <typename T>
class Pair {
    public:
    Pair(T val) : value(val) {}

    bool operator==(const Pair& other) {
        return value == other.value;
    }

    private:
    T value;
};

template <>
class Pair<char*> {
    public:
    Pair(const char* val) {
        std::size_t size = std::strlen(val) + 1;
        value = new char[size];
        memcpy(value, val, size);
    }

    ~Pair() {
        delete value;
    }

    bool operator==(const Pair& other) {
        return std::strcmp(value, other.value) == 0;
    }

    private:
    char* value;
};

int main() {
    Pair<int> p1(5), p2(5), p3(4);
    Pair<char*> p4("Hey"), p5("Hey"), p6("Bye");

    std::cout << (p1 == p2) << '\n' << (p1 == p3) << '\n';
    std::cout << (p4 == p5) << '\n' << (p4 == p6) << '\n';
}
```